# What's a good term for "instruction cycle count-accurate" emulation / simulation?

Tags: emulation, terminology, simulator

Emulation is called [cycle-accurate](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1191/115) if the original system's cycle-synchronous behaviour is fully captured; for example, a cycle-accurate emulation of a CPU, executing an instruction, would first present the externally visible effects of what the original CPU would do in the first cycle of executing that instruction, then so on for the second and subsequent cycles.

**I am looking for an established name for a weaker property**, where a CPU emulator makes sure that overall, each instruction takes the same number of clock cycles to execute, but between those cycles, makes no effort to present each outside-visible effect at the same cycles.

So for example, a real CPU might execute something like `MOV $1234, R` in 8 cycles, setting the address bus to `$1200` in cycle 3, then to `$1234` in cycles 4 and 5, then put the value of the `R` register on the data bus in cycle 6. Now imagine there is an alternative implementation (be it an emulator, a replacement IC, or an FPGA implementation) that executes `MOV $1234, R` in 8 cycles, by doing nothing for 4, then putting `$1234` on the address bus and the value of `R` on the data bus in cycle 5, and then does nothing for 3 more cycles, would not be cycle-accurate, but it would meet my definition.

Comment: @Justme yes, but in my example, the address bus (which of course is visible externally, by memory and memory-mapped peripherals) doesn't behave like the real thing cycle-by-cycle.

Comment: OK so I misunderstood that part a little. So the implementation would run at exactly correct speed in regard to correct clock cycles per instruction, but for example reads and writes over bus to video and audio chips would happen at wrong clock cycle? If the system is sensitive to that then it can cause issues and the whole system would not be cycle-accurate.

Comment: there are more therms for this (I do not think there is official one as emulation started mostly as hobby for programmers so no language normalization...) `clock-tics`,`time bursting`,`cycle count accuracy`. see [Question about cycle counting accuracy when emulating a CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33317202/2521214)

Comment: @Raffzahn consider demo scene productions...

Comment: @Cactus the accuracy requirement depends on which system you are emulating. For something like running demos on a C64, it is extremely sensitive that bus cycles happen at correct phase of the opcode regarding the video chip. For emulating a generic PC, it does not matter much as long as it's roughly in the right ballpark.

Comment: @Raffzahn You’re assuming purely software emulation, but I’m pretty sure that what Cactus has in mind here is things like FPGA-based hardware emulation of older chips, and when you’re doing that, it becomes very important whether your external hardware interfaces behave exactly like the original, approximately like the original, or not at all like the original. I’d argue it’s also on-topic, given that FPGA soft-core systems that would have to care about this type of thing are not uncommon when recreating old hardware (especially old microcomputers).

Comment: @Raffzahn I know my English is rusty ... but my understanding this question is just asking for **the name of the term** and not about new SW/HW development (that part is just an example of what the term should means). And knowing if emulator have synchronized execution or just clock-tics is very important. As the latter requires a lot of dirty hacks in order to "emulate peripherials" so a lot of SW that directly access specific components might not work (like custom tape loaders and border effects, etc...) on such emulation.

Comment: @Spektre you are exactly right about my intentions -- this is a question of terminology, as can be seen explicitly from the tags. I'm not sure why Raffzahn is being so difficult.

Comment: @Spektre Well a term is always about usage, and there are ofc differences between hardware and software. Most important here, if it would be about Hardware that question would not come up at all,as _"cycle exact"_ already implies that instructions are as well cycle exact. In this case any reference to instructions would be saying the same twice over.

Comment: @Cactus Because there is no terminology without environment. If it's about hardware, then _"cycle exact"_ already says everything. Adding more attributes are only needed if there's a difference from being cycle exact  in all respects - or if it's not about hardware but software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have once read [a blog post by the developer of mGBA, which simply uses ‘cycle-count accuracy’ for this property](https://mgba.io/2017/04/30/emulation-accuracy/), and seems to imply this is an established term. Looking up this phrase in a search engine seems to weakly corroborate this, as I found a number of other resources where the same term appears:

- Paper: [Mao-Lin Li, Chen-Kang Lo, Li-Chun Chen, Ren-Song Tsay, Hong-Jie Huang, Jen-Chieh Yeh, ‘A Formal Full Bus TLM Modeling for Fast and Accurate Contention Analysis’](http://sasimi.jp/new/sasimi2012/files/program/archive/pdf/p147_R2-1.pdf) (some of the same authors have also collaborated on a number of other papers where the same term appears)
- Paper: [Oana Boncalo, Alin Dobre, Alexandru Amaricai, Andrei Tanase, ‘A cycle-count-accurate simulation platform with enhanced design exploration capability’](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/2263019.2263033) (cites some of the papers previously mentioned)
- Book: [Andreas Hoffmann, Heinrich Meyr, Rainer Leupers, *Software Tools for Application Design*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-4538-2_7)
- Brochure: [Texas Instruments, ARM Simulator Datasheet (v4.6)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sprs397/sprs397.pdf?ts=1617084653068) (this one seems to conflate it with cycle accuracy, so beware)
- [README file for the MCS6502 emulator](https://github.com/bzotto/MCS6502/blob/d3c4b37618b76f3eb670f43a273f469b47da6b56/README.md)
- [Wikipedia page for ARMulator as of March 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ARMulator&oldid=350501204) (it cites no references, so I put this one last; I mention it mostly for the sake of establishing how old the term is)

As I remember, when I first encountered that blog post, I have never seen those terms before, but my rough knowledge of how CPUs work allowed me to correctly guess what they referred to right away when I saw them contrasted with each other. If you do similarly, I think there should be no misunderstandings.

Answer (score 6):

I have described such systems as “cycle-approximate”. Some [research papers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10766-018-0566-x), I [found](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1383762116300297) in a [short search](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-28305-5_17) session agree with this terminology.

It is slightly broader than you use it here, and would indicate to me that some portion of the simulator was incomplete, for example cache modeling, prefetchers, or other complex micro-architectural or system/bus level behaviours.